# why do I have to rewrite my js file every time to get my web socket working?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I created a simple web socket in javascript I'm using Nodejs to run it.
Every time I start it up, it doesn't work right off.  I have to close the connection, edit the js file, save it, change the js file back to how it was to begin with, run it again and it works.
I'm not actually changing the js file?  So why does it not work at first and then it works after messing with it?

To expand on my previous question.
I've been able to create the web socket.  This is being used to create a log file for Minecraft education edition (since that doesn't make any logs.)

I think my problem is I do not know how to properly set up the subscription to the messages.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. You haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Assuming you're following a tutorial 100% both client/server should be able to connect no issues and send messages. If you're constantly refreshing/restarting the connection without properly closing it or just too often! Browser will time out for a while and requires a full restart.

Comment: Ok I think I finally figured it out.  I was trying to subscribe to multiple events in a single command request.  I had to create a separate command request for each event I needed to subscribe to.